# Microsoft teams I want to add a team and add members at the same time . using graph api, c#

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to make a team and immediately add members .

I use this code when make a team.

```
var team = new Team
            {
                DisplayName = displayName,
                Description = description,
                AdditionalData = additionalData

            };

 await graphClient.Teams
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(team);
```

It does not return the team ID.

I've been getting a team ID as the display name of the team.

Do it this way, sometimes I can't bring team id.
Because there is a delay at the time the team is made.

I want to add a team and add members at the same time.
Is there a way to create a team and immediately get an ID returned?

Thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please let us know what APIs you are using, any lines of code, what your try has been so far, etc.

Comment: Sometime it takes sometime to get the Team created and that is the reason you are getting null id in return. Best way is to separate the logic of creating team and adding members/owners.